# Почему у меня не изменяется глобальная переменная?

Tags: javascript

Суть моей программы: на моем сайте есть поле для ввода имени, это имя должно сохраняться для того чтобы вывестись во всплывающем модальном окне.
Проблема в том, что глобальная переменная username не меняется после введения имени пользователя, и в модальном окне выводит значение, которое я объявил до выполнения функции nameForm().
Вот код:

```
window.username = "test";

function nameForm(){
    username = document.name.user_name_text.value; 
    alert("Здравствуйте, " + username +"!"); //выводит окно с введенным именем
}

function openPopup(){
    ...
    document.getElementById("popupNameUser").innerHTML = username;//выводит не введенное значение, а "test"
    ...
}
```

Comment: Функцию внутри функции вызывать, не?

Comment: где и когда вызываются данные функции?

Comment: первая функция вызывается при нажатии на кнопку под формой, куда пользователь вводит свое имя

Comment: а вторая вызывается при нажатии на кнопку открытия модального окна

Comment: если сначала нажать кнопку под формой, а потом на кнопку открытия модального окна - то все должно работать верно. Есть вероятность что "кнопка под формой" обновляет страницу, в этом случае естественно ничто никуда не запишется. Приведи разметку с формой и кнопкой.

Comment: вы были правы. страница действительно обновлялась и все сбрасывалось. спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score -1):

А если так?

```js
window.username = "test";

function nameForm(){
    window.username = document.name.user_name_text.value; 
    alert("Здравствуйте, " + window.username +"!"); //выводит окно с введенным именем
}

function openPopup(){
    ...
    document.getElementById("popupNameUser").innerHTML = window.username;//выводит не введенное значение, а "test"
    ...
}
```

Comment: все равно выводит test